# vb.net An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred

Tags: vb.net

I get the above error message when I run the below code :

```
  Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SkedDataBasis.mdf;Integrated Security=True").ConnectionString)
```

Supposedly cn is Nothing. As a newbie and after much research I cannot find my mistake. Any help to make me understand my missing would be much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: do you have a setting record named "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SkedDataBasis.mdf;Integrated Security=True" in the connection strings part of your app.config \ web.config file ?

Comment: You need to use the **name** of your connection to read it from your app settings - not the entire connection string itself.

Comment: Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-4)

Comment: Thank you guys. I put the following in my app.config : <connectionStrings> 

<add name="SQLConnStr" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SkedDataBasis.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 

</connectionStrings>. I then used SQLConnStr as the name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)